# Converted from pytorch to coreml model is too large

Tags: python, ios, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I am trying to convert my pytorch(.pth) model to coreml(.mlmodel) using the coremltools. The size of my initial pth file is about 218mb and I use the following code for conversion.

```
model = model.UNet_ConvLSTM(config.img_channel, config.class_num).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(config.pretrained_path))
model.eval()
input = rand_tensor = torch.rand((1, 5, 3, 128, 256), device=device)
print(input.shape)
trace = torch.jit.trace(model, input)
mlmodel = ct.convert(
    trace,
    inputs=[ct.TensorType(name="input", shape=input.shape)],
)
mlmodel.save("unetlstm.mlmodel")
```

The conversions is successful but the output file is about 900mb large. Why could that happen and what could I do to decrease the size of the model?

Comment: You can use [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to examine your Core ML model to see what is inside.

Comment: Did you solve it?